# Increase mouse speed over the limit? (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mouse-pointer

I just deactivated mouse acceleration (through gnome-tweaks) but now the mouse is a little bit slow for my liking. I went into settings (GUI version) and maximized the speed, but I would like it even faster (without acceleration). Is there any other way?

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I tried to edit the values of `xinput` as one of the answers in similar questions, but my value of (`libinput Accel Speed (-1,1)` is in max value 1.0 and I can't change it to any bigger value)

Comment: Did you try going to the Ubuntu forums and docs?

Comment: I checked the docs, but I think only shows the GUI mode (through settings). I haven't ask in ubuntu forums, I guess I will ask there.